# not search by only lastname

Tags: c#, sql

In my webapp, I have a search box so that I can search my database using the firstname or lastname and it will display the result in my web app.User input the firstname or lastname.if search by firstname query is running ok but if user search by only last name it shows all data in table not shows data like by lastname

```
 string sql = @"SELECT opd_id AS [OPD No]
       , opd_date AS DATE
       , opd_dpt AS DEPARTMENT
       , opd_pfname + ' ' + opd_plname AS [Patient NAME]
       , opd_age AS AGE
       , opd_gender AS GENDER
       , opd_mob AS [MOBILE NO]
       , opd_fthrname AS [FATHER NAME]
       , opd_hsbndname AS [HUSBAND NAME]
       FROM tbl_OPD 
        WHERE opd_pfname like'%" + fname + @"%' 
        OR opd_plname like'%" + lname + @"% '
        ORDER BY DATE DESC";
```

Comment: What opd_pfname actually had?

Comment: Anybody up for a game of SQL injection?  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: opd_pfname,opd_plname is column name

Comment: The problem is that, when 'fname' is empty, you are accepting every record. 'opd_pfname' is always 'like %%'

Answer (score 2):

Extra white space in

```
OR opd_plname like'%" + lname + @"% '
```

White space                                                    ^

Also, beware of [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which you can fix with [prepared sql statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and parameter bindings

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code it **could** be that you only have either of the `fname` or `lname` variables populated. Assuming that this is the case you could use this code.

```
// this assumes that you have only have 1 input for both the first name and lastname 
// and are storing it in a variable named searchForName
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONFIGURATION_CONNECTION_STRING"))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT opd_id AS [OPD No], opd_date AS DATE, opd_dpt AS DEPARTMENT, opd_pfname + ' ' + opd_plname AS [Patient NAME], opd_age AS AGE, opd_gender AS GENDER, opd_mob AS [MOBILE NO], opd_fthrname AS [FATHER NAME], opd_hsbndname AS [HUSBAND NAME] FROM tbl_OPD WHERE (opd_pfname like @p0 OR opd_plname like @p0) ORDER BY DATE DESC", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p0", string.Format("%{0}%", searchForName)));

        // rest of your code here E.G., sComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

If you know that both variables are populated try this code block

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONFIGURATION_CONNECTION_STRING"))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT opd_id AS [OPD No], opd_date AS DATE, opd_dpt AS DEPARTMENT, opd_pfname + ' ' + opd_plname AS [Patient NAME], opd_age AS AGE, opd_gender AS GENDER, opd_mob AS [MOBILE NO], opd_fthrname AS [FATHER NAME], opd_hsbndname AS [HUSBAND NAME] FROM tbl_OPD WHERE (opd_pfname like @p0 OR opd_plname like @p1) ORDER BY DATE DESC", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p0", string.Format("%{0}%", searchForFirstName)));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1", string.Format("%{0}%", searchForLastName)));

        // rest of your code here E.G., sComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

PS. As others have said the code shown here is somewhat insecure and you should do everything to avoid Sql Injection attacks.